# Does Rails do automatic casting before validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, callback, update-attributes

I have some form and I pass params to the update_attributes. There is also some value, which is an integer (in a database), but in form it is a text, which I want to parse in before_validation.

controller:

```
@organization.update_attributes(params[:organization])
```

model:

```
before_validation do
  logger.info(self.capital.to_s)

  return if self.capital.blank?
  self.capital = self.capital.gsub(/([$\,\s]|\.\d+)/, '') unless self.capital.is_a?(Fixnum)
  self.capital = nil if self.capital < 1
end
```

The problem is, I expect in `before_validation`, that self.capital is still a string. But it's an integer. So somewhere before Rails automaticly do `.to_i` casting. How can I prevent this / solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can work on your `@attributes` instance variable (accessible also through `attributes_before_type_cast` instance method).

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to manipulate capital before you save it, you can use an intermediate field -- so you'd put "capital_selection" on your form, and wrap it.

```
def capital_selection
  capital
end

def capital_selection=(other)
  self.capital = Integer(other)

  rescue ArgumentError
  self.errors.add(:capital_selection, "is not an integer")
end
```